# R Function Input

Tags: r, function

I have a function:

```
x <- function(x,interval)
quanitle(interval)
```

Is there a way that I can make it so that the function automatically transforms the user input ("80%","90%") into something like c(0.010,0.90) and c(0.050,0.95)

So that when when user inputs:

```
x(2,interval="90%")
```

R essentially runs this:

```
x(2,c(0.05,0.95))
```

Comment: Not quite..I am looking for a way that R automatically interprets the input "90%" as "c(0.05,0.95)"

Comment: What's the logic behind that? Do you want `confint`?

Comment: What is the logic of `x(2,interval="90%")` turning into `x(2,c(0.05,0.95))`

Comment: Because quantile(90%) is invalid, whereas quantile(c(0.05,0.95)) gives a valid input. I want the user to input 90 % into my function and quantile to evaluate(c(0.05,0.95))

Comment: How do you decide what is valid and what is invalid? Why 90% turns into `c(0.05,0.95)` and not `c(0.1,0.9)` ?

Comment: That is what I want to figure out. I want to write code so that 90% is automatically converted into c(0.05,0.95) within the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try the code like below

```
interval <- "90%"
u <- as.numeric(gsub("\\D+","",interval))/100
(1-c(u,-u))/2
```

which gives

```
> (1-c(u,-u))/2
[1] 0.05 0.95
```